# Settings has been deleted with root system app remover

Tags: applications, settings

I know its dumb I deleted my settings on accident with a root system app remover please help i cant factory reset my phone and i really want to reset it to give it to my brother for christmas

Answer (score 1):

You need to flash the stock ROM of your phone. The process for doing that, and where you can find a stock ROM for your phone, are both different for each model of phone.